# pstools on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: windows-7, psexec

Is it possible to use pstools, especially psshutdown.exe, on Windows 7 (64 bit)? It seems it doesn't work, at least if UAC is enabled.

Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: More info? Domain? Do you have the exe copied to both machines at %Systemroot%

Comment: PSTools work fine on Win7 64-bit with UAC enabled.  Perhaps explain exactly how you're trying to use them?

Comment: I can confirm the entire PS toolset works. Actually I just used PSexec this morning to push out new gateway configs for some static IP PCs

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to give the "/accepteula" switch the first time you use it.  Otherwise it will seem not to work.  Also, make sure you're using the proper creds.